# Pyramidal tiff images in map box

Tags: mapbox

1. May I know if map box supports medical  displaying medical images besides displaying maps.
2. Does it supports pyramidal tiff images

Answer (score 0):

> May I know if map box supports medical displaying medical images besides displaying maps.

Yes, see [this post](http://www.macwright.org/2012/08/13/images-as-maps.html): you can trick the software into rendering non-geo data.

> Does it supports pyramidal tiff images

Yes, if you are referring to [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/), the Mapbox tool you would use to render images with.